# center two text views horizontally aligned

Tags: android-layout

here is the code I have, I am unable to keep both the text views exactly to the center of the screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@mipmap/home_background"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        tools:context="com.couchbunny.www.MainActivity">

        <ImageView
            android:id = "@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/icon"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal = "true"
            android:layout_centerVertical = "true"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/couch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="19sp"
            android:layout_below = "@id/icon"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="couch"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="19sp"
            android:layout_below = "@id/icon"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/couch"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="bunny"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#f7ca18"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Current output

[image]

Desired output
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@mipmap/home_background"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
tools:context="com.couchbunny.www.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id = "@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/icon"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal = "true"
    android:layout_centerVertical = "true"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below = "@id/icon"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/couch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="19sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="couch"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="19sp"
        android:layout_below = "@id/icon"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/couch"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="bunny"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#f7ca18"
        />

</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That worked out for me, if you can explain me your code, it would be helpful for me.

Comment: You should give gravity center for layout